# The infinitely admissable sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

In this challenge we'll compute an infinite minimal admissible sequence.

The sequence for this challenge starts with `a(1) = 1`.

We continue this sequence by finding `a(n)` as the smallest possible number such that `a(n) > a(n-1)` and for every prime `p`, the set `{a(i) mod p : 1 ≤ i ≤ n}` has at most `p-1` elements.

Write a program or function that takes positive integer `n` and outputs `a(n)`. Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

Example:

`a(6)` is `19`, rather than, say `17` because `[1,3,7,9,13,19]` (the previous terms) is admissible while `[1,3,7,9,13,17]` is not.

`[1,3,7,9,13,17]` is not admissible, because for the base `3`, after taking the modulo of each term with `3`, we obtain `[1,0,1,0,1,2]` which contains every non-negative number smaller than `3`, our chosen base.

For `[1,3,7,9,13,19]` however, it would be impossible to come up with a base such that the list after modulo contains every non-negative integer smaller than such base.

---

Reference:

- [OEIS A020498](https://oeis.org/A020498)

---

Testcases:

```
a(1) = 1
a(2) = 3
a(3) = 7
a(4) = 9
a(5) = 13
a(6) = 19
a(7) = 21
a(8) = 27
a(9) = 31
a(10) = 33
a(100) = 583
```

Comment: Can we use 0-based index?

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89786/8478)

Comment: @LeakyNun For this one, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 44 bytes

```
-:[1]r:[1]cit.
t<gX=:?rc.'(l:2eLg:.rz:%adlL)
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LTpbMV1yOlsxXWNpdC4KdDxnWD06P3JjLicobDoyZUxnOi5yejolYWRsTCk&input=MTA&args=Wg)

`100` takes about a minute here, so be patient if you want to try `100`.

#### Predicate 0 (main predicate)

```
-:[1]r:[1]cit.
-:[1]r:[1]c     create array [[1], input-1, 1]
           i    iterate: [1] as input, iterate (input-1) times, predicate 1
            t.  last element is the output
```

#### Predicate 1 (auxiliary predicate)

```
t<gX=:?rc.'(l:2eLg:.rz:%adlL)
t<                              last element of input < Temp
  gX                            [Temp] = X
   X=                           Assign a value to X, which assigns
                                a value to Temp
   X :?rc.                      [Input,X] concatenated is output
         .'(                )   The following about the output cannot
                                be proven:
            l:2eL                   L is a number between 2 and length
                                    of output, inclusive
                Lg:.rz:%a           every element of output, taken modulo L,
                         dlL        after removing duplicates, has length L
```

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 91 bytes

```
(n,a=[i=1])=>a[n]||f(n,a.every((_,j)=>(j+=2)>new Set(b.map(e=>e%j)).size,b=[...a,+++])?b:a)
```

Zero-indexed. Due to its recursive nature, only works for the first 450 terms, but computes a(99)=583 almost instantly.